# Silverlight extensions, does the client need them too?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I use Controls from Silverlight SDK and Silverlight Toolkit and I'm curious if the client has to install the packages as well?

How do I build such an application correctly to deploy it afterwards?

EDIT:

I just ask because I'm unable to get my application to run on a client running a bare SL4 runtime. It just throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei System.Windows.Application.Application_Starting(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   bei MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   bei MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I use the VS2010 devserver to deploy the application to the client.

The app makes use of a WCF Service I also serve by VS2010 for now, it also contains a "clientaccesspolicy.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install those packages on the client side,
it's will be part of your xap file,

and about the server running your Silverlight application,
Silverlight is a client technology and can be hosted on any web server.  It can be any type of web server that is capable of delivering the XAP file along with the correct content MIME type from the server (application/x-silverlight-app).
As long as it does that, we don’t care what type of web server it is delivering the XAP file.

Comment: But why does my Application crash during _Starting on a client which has a bare SL4 runtime installed?

Comment: I included the exception in the question.

Comment: You are using WCF in your application? Read also my note about the server running the silverlight

Comment: Yes, i use a WCF service in my application.

Comment: Read the following link http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2008/10/19/blocked-by-the-silverlight-managedruntimeerror-4004.aspx

Comment: I do serve a clientaccesspolicy.xml

Comment: The error can come from alot of things, it can be unsuccessful databinding or not Initialize properties or variables. I think you should open new question and change the subject. It has no connection to the SDK or Toolkit